# Matrix-vector convergence proof

Tags: matrices, convergence-divergence

I'm looking at a proof, and I'm not very familiar with matrix convergence, so I don't understand what's happening here. 
Is it possible to provide some commentary or explanation on what's going on in each of these proof steps?

Proposition: If $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}M_k = M$ for a sequence of matrices compatible with $x$ (for which $x_k\rightarrow x$), then $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} M_kx_k = Mx.$$

Proof: 
$$\begin{align*}
\left\Vert M_{k}x_{k}-M{x}\right\Vert  & \leq\left\Vert M_{k}x_{k}-M_{k}x\right\Vert +\left\Vert M_{k}x-M {x}\right\Vert \\
 & \leq\left\Vert M_{k}\right\Vert \cdot\left\Vert x_{k}-x\right\Vert +\left\Vert M_{k}-M\right\Vert \cdot\left\Vert x\right\Vert \qquad\text{Factoring out }M_k,x\\
\left\Vert M_{k}\right\Vert  & \leq\left\Vert M_{k}-M\right\Vert +\left\Vert M\right\Vert 
\end{align*}$$

In particular, what's happening in the first and last lines (perhaps a bit more explicitly)?

Comment: What are the $x_m$? (Using $M,m$ as above is likely to cause confusion and delay.)

Comment: If $M_k \to M, x_k \to x$ then by continuity of multiplication we have $M_k x_k \to M x$.

Comment: @copper.hat Edited, changing m to k

Comment: You should also add that $x_k \to x$, presumably?

Comment: @copper.hat yup

Comment: If a sequence converges, then the sequence is bounded. The last line is just showing that you can put an explicit bound on $\|M_k\|$. But the above proof is really just about proving continuity of matrix multiplication.